# How do I display RSS feeds from other web sites

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

I am trying to display a blog: http://miletich2.blogspot.co.uk/ on my clients Wordpress site and as I have been looking around people have been recommending `simple pie` and their demo works great, but their Wordpress plugin hasn't been updated in 2 years and has loads of bugs.

Does any one know of another plugin that has the same functionality? Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [fetch_feed](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/fetch_feed/) function.

E.g. to show 5 posts with the provided blog:

```
<?php 

    // Get a SimplePie feed object from the specified feed source.
    $rss = fetch_feed('http://miletich2.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default?alt=rss');

    $maxitems = 0;

    if (!is_wp_error($rss)) { // Checks that the object is created correctly

        // Figure out how many total items there are, but limit it to 5.
        $maxitems = $rss->get_item_quantity(5);

        // Build an array of all the items, starting with element 0 (first element).
        $rss_items = $rss->get_items(0, $maxitems);

    }
?>

<ul>
    <?php if ($maxitems == 0) : ?>
        <li><?php _e('No posts found', 'text-domain'); ?></li>
    <?php else : foreach ($rss_items as $item) : ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url($item->get_permalink()); ?>">
                    <?php echo esc_html($item->get_title()); ?>
                </a>
                <span>(<?php echo $item->get_date(get_option('date_format')); ?>)</span>
            </li>
    <?php endforeach; endif; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: hmm,  get a massive error:
it just tells me the feed isn't available

Comment: It's because `split()` is deprecated and removed from PHP 7. I just updated the answer. Hope it help!

Comment: awesome thanks! One more question. Is there way to add some of the blog text with a read more button and truncate?

Comment: Yes, you can use `$item->get_description()` to get full post content then truncate it. You can use `$item->get_link()` to get the URL. For more info, you can read at [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-simplepie.php)

Comment: Whoops! remove `include_once ABSPATH . WPINC . '/feed.php'`. Look like `fetch_feed` is ready to use on front-end.